# C/C++: How to properly convert "unsigned int *" value to "unsigned int"?

Tags: c++, c, memory, unsigned, unsigned-integer

I have an "unsigned int *" value, and I need to convert it to a simple "unsigned int",
so I could transfer it to a function. But, unfortunately,
when I try to do a simple cast, the value gets changed:

```
Code:

unsigned int * addr;

...

fprintf(stdout, "=== addr: %08x ===\n", addr); fflush(stdout);
fprintf(stdout, "=== casted addr: %08x ===\n", (unsigned int)addr);


Output:

=== addr: fc880000 ===
=== casted addr: 400eff20 ===
```

Please tell me, how to convert this value properly, so it doesn't change during the conversion?

Comment: ...There is no C/C++ which one are you using?

Comment: You are printing two different variables: `addr` and `address`!

Comment: @Mike C, but a C++ solution would be interesting as well.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn sorry, the sample of code I provided was old. Fixed now.

Comment: Why would you expect the values to be the same? In one instance, you are printing out the value of addr, which is a pointer, in the other instance, you are printing out the de-referenced value of addr.

Comment: _Why_ would you want to typecast the pointer? Pointers can be passed to functions like any other variable.

Comment: Also remember that the size of a pointer and the size of an `unsigned int` doesn't have to be the same.

Comment: Do you need pointer itself, or the value it addresses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use `*addr`. This is valid and should always work. In case you need to get the **value** of the pointer instead of the value **pointed to** by the pointer, you will need a larger type. Typically the value of an `unsigned int*` is 64 bit, while `unsigned int` is only 32 bit.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems that I needed a larger type.The cast (long unsigned int) is working perfectly!

Comment: I would not say the size of int is typically 32. Especially nowadays with lots of 64 bit systems around.

Comment: @JakeBadlands There are two standard integer types that are explicitly made for holding a pointer value: `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`, depending on whether you want the integer value to be signed or unsigned. Anything else is not guaranteed to be the right size depending on the platform specifics.

Comment: @LokiAstari: `int` is 32 bits on just about any 32 or 64 bit platform you're likely to encounter, so it's fair to call that "typical".

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a pointer, like

```
unsigned int * addr;
```

The value of that pointer will be the address of the `unsigned int` it points to.

When you want to get the value of the `unsigned int` it points to you use the dereference operator `*`:

```
unsigned int value = *addr;
```

So what you see in the second output line is the contents of what `addr` points to.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a pointer of some type, and you need to convert it to just the type, you just need to deference the pointer.

```
void foo(unsigned int some_value);

...

int main()
{

    unsigned int * addr = 0x12345678; // some address holding an unsigned int
    foo(*addr);  // some function taking a unsigned int
```

No need to typecast anything here because you're not changing the type. Note in your code the "value" doesn't change:

```
// prints the address
fprintf(stdout, "=== addr: %08x ===\n", addr); 

// prints the value at that address
fprintf(stdout, "=== casted addr: %08x ===\n", *(unsigned int *)addr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not changing the value. In

```
fprintf(stdout, "=== addr: %08x ===\n", addr); fflush(stdout);
```

You are accessing the address of the pointer.

In

```
fprintf(stdout, "=== casted addr: %08x ===\n", *(unsigned int *)address);
```

you are accessing the value pointed to.

Comment: Well, just do as people said and dereference your pointer like fprintf(stdout, "=== casted addr: %08x ===\n", (unsigned int)(*addr));